# What is the second to docker0 part of docker veth interface on host side?

Tags: docker, networking, namespaces

By default we have a bridge named `docker0` on host machine as one component of docker networking.
When we run a docker container, it creates a `vethxxx` pipe which binds docker0 with one point and container with the other point, named `eth0`.

I'm trying to find the trace of those `eth0` interface on host machine.
I've expected to find some network namespace via:

```
ip netns show
```

But it's clear. So how could I see the representation of a container's `eth0` interface on host machine?

Comment: It could be useful -  https://forums.docker.com/t/relationship-between-interface-vethxxxxx-and-container/12872

Answer (score 0):

Generally, each container has an isolated network namespace on host. And the interface `eth0` in a container is encapsulated in a network namespace(aka sandbox in Docker terminology). So if you want to see `eth0` on host side, you must enter its network namespace first.

But docker containers' network namespaces lay in different directory from those created manually. They lay in `/var/run/docker/netns`. So we need create a soft link to `/var/run/netns`.

1. ln -s /var/run/docker/netns /var/run/netns
2. ip netns list
3. ip netns exec xxxx ip addr show

Thus, you could see the other side of veth on host machine in each isolated network namespace.

```
root@Light-G:/var/lib# ip netns exec 459c238c2a4f ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: eth0@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:0a:c7:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.10.199.2/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:aff:fe0a:c702/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```